# In node.js development, in a child process, it is better to clear a timeout on exit, rather than close, correct?

Tags: node.js

In node.js development, in a child process, it is better to clear a timeout on exit, rather than close, correct?  As I understand it, close fires on io stream release, which could be shared, but exit fires when child process is released.  Just as a test I attached functions to both events, and exit appears to fire before close fires.  This seems rather confusing, in light of my understanding noted above.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, of course, no sooner than I post the question... I found the answer shortly after.  In the documentation on child events I found, "Note that when the 'exit' event is triggered, child process stdio streams might still be open." Nuts, duhe.